# How do I write an rspec test in Rails 3 to test if a user is signed with authlogic after being created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, authlogic

I'm porting my app from a custom authentication mechanism to authlogic and I'm having trouble figuring out how to test that a new user is logged in after it is created. My old test was the following:

```
describe UsersController do
.
.
.
before(:each) do
  activate_authlogic
  @attr = { :username => "New User", :email => "user@example.com",
    :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" }
end
.
.
.
 it "should sign the user in" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    controller.should be_signed_in
 end
```

where signed_in? is defined in app/helpers/user_sessions_helper.rb and is included in the application controller:

```
# check for a signed in user. returns true if current_user is not nil.        
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

I'm expecting this test to pass but signed_in? is returning false. Any ideas? My guess is that I should be asking UserSession if :user is signed in but I'm not sure how authlogic allows me to do this.

Any hints, tips, or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to write a test that passes - now I just have to figure out if the logic in the test is correct :)

```
it "should sign the user in" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    @user_session = UserSession.find
    @user_session.user.should_not == nil
end
```

This at least checks that there is *a* user signed in, but it doesn't show that the user, that was just created, is signed in. I think it needs a little more work.